# Android crash reports are not showing up in Google play console's ANRs & Crashes report

Tags: android, android-testing, android-billing, android-developer-api, google-play-developer-api

I'm currently testing Google play's billing library for in-app subscriptions on my android app. I've created the subscriptions and have released my app to the internal test track. However, when I try going through my billing flow, my app is crashing for an unknown reason. I'm sending the crash report when this happens, but when I look in my android vitals in the ANRs and Crashes report, my crash report data is nowhere to be found. Instead, Google Console is saying I have "no errors found for the selected criteria".

---

Why is my crash data not registering? What am I doing wrong here? I just want to find out where my error is. I have to test my app as a release because otherwise the google billing api won't work. For example, when trying to test on my emulator I get an error response code 5, which says that my application isn't setup for in-app billing. When testing on the internal testing track, I get past this check and start my billing flow, but then it just crashes.

---

Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Play's Crash Reporting is very delayed. It can take 18 hours for a crash log to show up there.

Instead, you really should be installing the APK directly on your device and using Android Studio's logcat feature to get the log instantly (filter by Error and search by your app's package name)

If you can't do that, then implement Firebase Crashlytics. Google has a [handy guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started) for you. Crashlytics reports are nearly instant.

Comment: Oh I see. I was just being impatient. I had tried to test by manually installing the apk directly, but the billing api became unresponsive. The app didn't crash though. Maybe I need to look into this Firebase Crashlytics.

Comment: So I added the Crashlytics api to my application. Now when it crashes the data shows up immediately in Fabric. Thank you for that suggestion!

Comment: @Michael use Firebase not Fabric. Fabric is shutting down at the end of the year.

Comment: Oh really? Okay, I'm switching to Firebase then.

Answer (score 0):

There are also some crashes, like TransactionTooLargeException that never get uploaded to console.

Answer (score -1):

Usually, it takes a day or two for the Console to update the statistics. I would recommend using more real-time crash tracking services: Fabric, Firebase.

Another point, a common mistake when testing in-app billing on emulator and getting the

> application isn't set up for in-app billing

error. Make sure your emulator has Google services installed. It's usually better to test on a real device.